# TS2322: Type Question is not assignable to type ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is baffling me, even after reading the TS error.

**Error**: `TS2322: Type  Question  is not assignable to type  ReactNode`

[image]

```
export default class TeamProfile extends Component<{ company: Organization }> {
    render() {
        const { company } = this.props;
        const { teamProfile } = company.interview;

        return (
            <div className="all-100">
                <p className="section-heading bold font-22" id="ft-team-profile">
                    Team Profile
                </p>
                <div className="all-100 padding-left-30 align-left">
                    {teamProfile.teamContext.answer && (
                        <div className="all-100 align-left padding-bottom-10">
                            <span className="bold blue">{teamProfile.teamContext.question}</span>
                            <TeamContextAnswer answer={teamProfile.teamContext.answer} className="ft-answer" />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
export interface TeamProfile {
    teamContext: {
        question: Question;
        answer: Array<string>;
    };
}

export interface Question {
    question: string;
    answer: Array<string>;
    details: Array<string>;
    description: string;
}
```

Comment: What's the goal here exactly? That interpolation (`{}`) is telling the JSX compiler to render an object as an HTML node. Typescript is telling you that doesn't work. It won't, even in plain JS.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `teamProfile.teamContext.question.question` which is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the type definition of `ReactNode`:

```
type ReactNode =
        | ReactElement
        | string
        | number
        | Iterable<ReactNode>
        | ReactPortal
        | boolean
        | null
        | undefined
        | DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED_EXPERIMENTAL_REACT_NODES[keyof DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED_EXPERIMENTAL_REACT_NODES];
```

`teamProfile.teamContext.question` is a `Question` type that is not compatible with `ReactNode`

You should use

```
<span className="bold blue">
  {teamProfile.teamContext.question.question}
</span>
```